# What's wrong with the intersections?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Why the points `G` and `H` (seem to) coincide?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,font=\small]
\clip (-4,-2.5) rectangle (8,2.5);
\coordinate (A) at (0,0) coordinate (B) at (5.1,0) coordinate (O) at ($(A)!.5!(B)$);
\path (A)--(B);
\draw[thick,name path=L1,blue] (A) circle (2cm); 
\draw[thick,name path=L2,blue] (B) circle (1cm);
\draw[name path=L3] 
  let 
  \p1=($(O)-(A)$) %jari-jari
  in
  (O) circle ({veclen(\x1,\y1)});

\draw[thick,name path=L4,red] (A) circle (1cm);
\path [name intersections={of = L3 and L4, by={C,D}}]; 

\draw[name path=g1] (A)--($(A)!2.1cm!(C)$);
\draw[name path=g2] (A)--($(A)!2.1cm!(D)$);

\path [name intersections={of = L1 and g1, by={E}}]; 
\path [name intersections={of = L1 and g2, by={F}}]; 
\draw[name path=g3] (E)--($(E)!6cm!90:(C)$);
\path [name intersections={of = L2 and g3, by={G}}]; 
\draw[name path=g4,green] (F)--($(F)!6cm!-90:(D)$);
\path [name intersections={of = L2 and g4, by={H}}];

\draw[fill] (A) circle(1pt);
\draw[fill] (O) circle(1pt);
\draw[fill] (B) circle(1pt);
\draw[fill] (C) circle(1pt);
\draw[fill] (D) circle(2pt);
\draw[fill] (E) circle(2pt);
\draw[fill] (F) circle(2pt);
\draw[fill] (G) circle(1pt);
\draw[fill=red] (H) circle(2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems to me that in

```
\path [name intersections={of = L2 and g3, by={G}}];
```

the intersection is by `intersection-1`. Then the coordinate `G` is defined at `intersection-1`.

Maybe due to a precision problem there is no real intersection between `L2` and `g4`. So the coordinate `intersection-1` known from the last calculation is used to define coordinate `H`.

If you change the prefix for the intersection between `L2` and `g4` to e.g. `x`

```
\path [name intersections={of = L2 and g4, by={H},name=x}];
```

you get the error message `! Package pgf Error: No shape named x-1 is known.` and `H` is marked in the orgin.

---

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path
  (-2,-2)coordinate[label=below:A](A)
  (-2,2)coordinate[label=above:B](B)
  (2,2)coordinate[label=above:C](C)
  (2,-2)coordinate[label=below:D](D)
  (-3,0)coordinate[label=left:E](E)
  (3,0)coordinate[label=right:F](F)
;
\draw[green,name path=g1](A)--(B)node[left,pos=.25]{g1};
\draw[green,name path=g2](C)--(D)node[right,pos=.25]{g2};
\draw[blue,name path=g3](E)--(F)node[above,pos=.5]{g3};


\path [name intersections={of = g1 and g3, by={G}}];
\path [name intersections={of = g1 and g2, by={H}}];

\path[nodes=circle,draw,fill,inner sep=1pt]
  (G)node[label=above left:G]{}
  (H)node[inner sep=2pt,fill=red,label=below right:H]{}
;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

resulting in

[image]

While there is no intersection between `g1` and `g2` coordinate `H` is marked.

If I change the order of the calculations to

```
\path [name intersections={of = g1 and g2, by={H}}];
\path [name intersections={of = g1 and g3, by={G}];
```

or if I set a different prefix for the first calculation one using

```
\path [name intersections={of = g1 and g3, by={G},name=x}];
\path [name intersections={of = g1 and g2, by={H}}];
```

I get the error message `! Package pgf Error: No shape named intersection-1 is known.` and

[image]

Note that `H` is no in the origin.

---

**Suggestion for the picture**

Here is a suggestion for your picture using nodes for the blue circles and the `tangent cs` for the tangents.

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,font=\small,
  blue circle node/.style={draw,thick,blue,circle,transform shape,minimum size=2*#1,outer sep=0pt},
  ]
\newcommand\radius{1cm}
\newcommand\Radius{2cm}
%\clip (-4,-2.5) rectangle (8,2.5);
\coordinate (A) at (0,0) coordinate (B) at (5.1,0) coordinate (O) at ($(A)!.5!(B)$);
\path (A)--(B);
\node[blue circle node=\Radius](L1)at (A){};
\node[blue circle node=\radius](L2)at (B){}; 
\draw[name path=L3] 
  let 
  \p1=($(O)-(A)$), %jari-jari
  \n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)}
  in
  (O) circle [radius=\n1];

\draw[thick,name path=L4,red] (A) circle [radius=1cm];
\path [name intersections={of = L3 and L4, by={C,D}}]; 

\draw(A)--($(A)!{\Radius}!(C)$)coordinate(E)--([turn]0:0.1cm);
\draw(A)--($(A)!{\Radius}!(D)$)coordinate(F)--([turn]0:0.1cm);

\coordinate(G) at (tangent cs:node=L2,point={(E)},solution=2);
\coordinate(H) at (tangent cs:node=L2,point={(F)},solution=1);

\draw(E)--($(E)!6cm!(G)$);
\draw[green](F)--($(F)!6cm!(H)$);


\foreach \p in {A,O,B,C,G}\draw[fill](\p)circle[radius=1pt];
\foreach \p in {D,E,F}\draw[fill](\p)circle[radius=2pt];
\draw[fill=red] (H) circle[radius=2pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for  the `tangent cs:` never considered that one

Comment: I suppose that there is no real intersection between `g4` and `L2` due to a precision problem, because intersection between `g3` and `L2` is defined in a similar way a it doesn't fail. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Ignasi I think also that it is a precision problem. Therefore I have added this supposition to answer.